# Visual Basic 2008 auto-scan controls

Tags: vb.net

I have a form containes some controls (buttons) how i can make the program autoscan these controls one by one and whenever a button higlited I can bress enter to press this button. Using Visual Basic 2008

Comment: How do you mean highlighted? If it's got focus? Or if the mouse is over it?

Comment: and by highlighted you mean mouse hover ? pls rephrase/clarify your question to help us to help you

Comment: We can't answer this at the moment. We don't understand what you mean by highlighted.

Comment: Yes. it can be  got focus or mouse is over it.

Comment: thanks - I mean by highlighted:  got focus or mouse is over it automatically one by one separated by timer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to autoscan the controls, pressing TAB cycles through the controls on the form. Just press TAB until you have the right control selected and then use the `KeyDown` method for the control:

```
Private Sub Button1_KeyDown(byVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Button1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Windows.Forms.Keys.Enter Then
        ' Do whatever
    End If
End Sub
```

In the `If` Statement, I recommend you reference a custom Sub that you'll also reference in the `Button1_Click` event. This will allow you to do make sure that hitting Enter on the selected control and clicking on it do the same thing.

The only downside to this is that you have to write Event Handlers as shown above for every control on your form if that's what you want.

HTH